# Displaying chinese, cyrillic and korean fonts in AIR

Tags: android, ios, flash, air, string-table

I got a problem with the different languages on my game. I publish my game from Flash Professional CS5.5 to AIR for Android and AIR for iOS.

All languages are fine, except chinese, korean, russian. What do I need to do to display them?

I'm using an embeded font (arial) and I tested in word to display my texts in arial an there's no problem at all.

I tested this in my swf:

When I write the chinese text in a textfield, than the text will be displayed correctly, but when the text is dynamically added with the string-xml data the text will not be displayed correctly (only brackets and digits).

I hope you can help me.

Thanks and greetings

Comment: is your xml file encoding set to UTF-8 ? open it with an editor like notepad++ and check the encodding/

Comment: It's UFT-8 without BOM. And this is set by flash itself. I can't change it.

Comment: Are you setting the fontfamily style to the dynamically added Textfield ?

Comment: the textfields aren't dynamically added, they're inside movieclips and there is the font set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the problem was solved when I removed all embeded fonts.

The mainproblem with this resolve is, that all fonts are displayed in "sans" and you don't have uniquenes inside your game.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you do not use the existing fonts within the OS? I had written something sometime back that may help you. I have added the details on 
[How can I detect system Chinese, Korean, and English fonts without embedding one for each? (AIR mobile on Android and IOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23390203/how-can-i-detect-system-chinese-korean-and-english-fonts-without-embedding-one/23560056#23560056)